# HTTP/2が速いというのでやってみたいんですが

Tags: https

httpsにしなければならないというのですが、
オレオレ証明はSEO的にダメですか？

Comment: オレオレ証明書（大手CAの署名を受けていない証明書）を使う場面というのは関係者向けとか内輪向けとか、不特定多数に見せないサイトが多いと思うのですが、この場合SEO対策されていなくても問題ないでしょう。不特定多数向けのサイトでオレオレ証明書を使いたいのですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

結論から申し上げると「オレオレ証明書を用いたサイトを不特定多数に公開するくらいなら非暗号化のままのがマシ」といったところになるかと思います。

最近のSEOは疎いのですが、オレオレ証明書の場合、下記サイトにあるように警告画面が表示されるか、そもそもサイトが表示されません。

http://qiita.com/Sheile/items/dc91128e8918fc823562

Googleクローラの挙動はわかりませんが、Googleクローラ等に代表されるBOTはオレオレ証明書かどうかの判断ができない（悪意ある第三者が発行した証明書か判断できない）ために、おそらくクロール自体を行わないのはないかと想像します。
かといって証明書を取るにも費用がかかり、個人ユースでは手軽に導入できないため、どうしようかなぁといったところで立ち上がったプロジェクトがLet's Encryptです。

https://letsencrypt.org/

例えばお役所でもらう住民票と、道を歩いている誰だかよくわからない人からもらう住民票の場合、信用するのはどちらでしょうか？といったところでしょうか。
･･･例示が悪いですねハイ･･･。